# Perturbation of the spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, perturbation-theory

In a lecture note, in the demonstration of a result it is said that "*using analytic perturbation theory*" it is possible to deduce certain things. The reference is **Kato's** classic book, "*Perturbation theory for linear operators*". I'm not very familiar with the book and couldn't find the exact result or collection of results that would allow me to reach the conclusion made.

The result is very intuitive, a small perturbation in the operator leads to a small perturbation in the spectrum.

---

Let $X$ a Banach space (possibly infinite dimensional) and  $R: z \mapsto \text{Hom}(X,X)$ where the spectrum of $R(1)$ consists of an isolated simple eigenvalue at $1$ and a compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$.

From this i know that the spectrum of $R(1)$ consists of a subset of $\{ \lambda\in \mathbb{D}: |\lambda|\le \tau \}$ for some $\tau \in (0,1)$ and a simple isolated eigenvalue at $1$ with eigenprojection $P$. Fix some $\kappa\in(\tau,1)$ and let $R_A$ be a perturbation of $R(1)$, more precisely,  $R_A(z)=R(1)+(z-1)R'(1)$, (assume that R'(1) is well defined.)

We have that $z\mapsto R_A(z)$ is holomorphic, so, here it is mentioned that **Kato's book** (analytic perturbation theory) is used, to deduce that:

Exists $\delta$ and $P_A : B_{\delta}(1) \to \text{Hom}(X,X)$, $\lambda_A :B_{\delta}(1) \to \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic such taht:

1. $\lambda_A(z)$ is a simple eigenfunction of $R_A(z)$ with eigenprojection $P_A(z)$;
2. $|\lambda_A (z)|> \kappa$ and the rest of the spectrum of $R_A(z)$ is contained in $\{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C} : |\lambda|\le\kappa \}$

---

As I said, I could not find this result in the book and I would like to know from someone who is familiar with the theory of perturbation, any reference to this result or the collection of result that allows to conclude what was said.

**Edit:** I believe that one of the results used may be **Theorem 3.16** from Chapter 4 of Kato's book. The theorem can be seen [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=8ji2kN_D3BwC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA212#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Can you see that Theorem 3.16 of Chap. 4 gives you everything you need except for the holomorphic condition?

Comment: @pax kind of. I was unable to piece together the information in Theorem 3.16 to reach the conclusions I put in the post. As I am not familiar with the theory, it seems to me that something is missing...

Comment: You have to specify a bit about $R$ to guarantee that $R'(1)$ exists and is bounded. Other than that, the theorem guarantees the map you want exist, except that they are continuous not holomorphic. The proof can be used to show that for your case the maps are also holomorphic, but if the prior is not clear, I think you may benefit from a more careful reading of the section.

Comment: @pax thanks for the comments. You are correct, $R'(1)$ exists and is bounded. I wonder if you can help me with an answer. I'm reading the section, but like I said, I'm not getting to the conclusions.